Opamp Alternative Choice



In this study, this diagram was created for the preamplifier design. Is the LT1001 a correct match for the opamp? For the diagram above, I think pins 1 and 8 are Vos trim(white,pinB), pin 5 is NC(white,pinE)
Also, what could be alternative opamps for LT1001?
What do you think about this schematics?
This study:
Doctoral Dissertations - Hyomin Kim - Development of ground-based search -coil magnetometer systems in the polar regions and studies of ULF Pc 1--2 wave propagation in the ionospheric waveguide
Paper Link: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/215517548.pdf

what could be alternative opamps for LT1001?

You can use OP27AJGB.
